# SSIS -> updating Active Directory access denied exception

Tags: c#, ssis, active-directory, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SSIS to update an active directory entry. At first I used a script component which worked fined. Then I tried to optimize the control flow by putting the update into a script component and that is when it began that I got an "access denied" exception. After tests I gave up on the idea and tried to move back to the original script task but now I also got the same exception there.

After talks with the sys admins I found out the following:

- My AD user had the appropriate rights the whole time and the rights weren't changed from the time it worked
- During one of the failed tests with the original code they gave me admin rights but no effect on the exception

The exception occurs as soon as CommitChanges is called. The code itself is part of an SSIS package I ran from visual studio on my PC so it SHOULD use my user as far as I'm aware of.

Sourcecode example:

```
DirectoryEntry searchroot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XXXXXX.com");
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchroot, 
        "(&(objectClass=user)(sn=MySN))", new string[] {"info"}, SearchScope.Subtree))
{
    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    DirectoryEntry upd = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path);
    upd.Properties["info"].Value = "myTest";
    upd.CommitChanges();
    upd.Close();
}
```

The sn with MySN only yields one result. Also as info: I'm using SQL data tools 2014 and visual studio 2013

As like I said the rights for my user weren't changed and even giving my user admin rights didnt take care of the exception (despite the same code working a short while earlier). So my question is: What can have caused the problem as I'm honestly out of ideas there (or can it be that I'm mistaken with SSIS using my user there?).

Update:
Today the code without any changes to the code or AD works again oO I would really like to know what could have caused the problem as I'm absolutely not getting it and it just seems unstable to me for reasons unknown so far.

Comment: that says that something changed probably the trust from the AD to the SQL server.

Comment: hmmm what do you mean there? (according to the admins the only thing they had made from the time it frist worked to the time it stopped working was that they had added an user)

Comment: what I mean is something was changed to make it stop working and than changed again to make it work again. Things don't work and stop working randomly. The two main changes can be change of privileges of the SSIS user or the SQL box where the SSIS was running was not set as a trusted machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have the correct permissions on Active Directory?? To modifiy attributes in Active Directory you need the Replicate Directory Changes, including a DomainAdmin not necessarily have permissions to modify attributes of the Scheme:


To grant Replicate Directory Changes permission you can follow the next article:

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/303972/en-us

Comment: Yepp. I had the same rights the whole time while it worked, while it didnt work and while it worked again. During the time that it didnt work (and I got the message) the admins gave me even admin rights inside AD.